# Choosing a norm on a Lie algebra, that is "compatible" with the adjoint representation

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have the following problem:

Consider a compact Lie group $G$. Let $\mathfrak{g}$ denote its Lie algebra. We have the exponential map:
$$
exp: \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow G
$$
It is a fact that we may choose an $\epsilon > 0$ such that the restriction of $exp$ to $D_{\epsilon} \subset \mathfrak{g}$, the disc of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $0$ is injective.

Recall that there is an action of $G$ on $\mathfrak{g}$ given by the adjoint representation:

$$G \times \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$$
$$(g,x) \mapsto Ad_g(x)$$

Now my question is the following:

Can we choose a norm and an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $g \in G$, $\vert\vert x \vert \vert <\epsilon$ implies $\vert\vert Ad_gx\vert \vert <\epsilon$?

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? What examples have you looked at?

Comment: Yes, I mean for all $g \in G$. I have edited the question accordingly. 
So far I have only looked at examples where $G$ is abelian (in which case the above is true since $Ad_g$ acts trivially). I don't know about the general case and have no idea where to begin. The reason why I am asking is that this claim is implicit in a paper that I am reading, and since I have no background knowledge about Lie groups, I was hoping that somebody here might be able to help me.

Comment: Yes, for abelian $G$ it's trivial. In general you will need that $G$ is compact modulo its centre. Have you heard of the Killing form?

Comment: Can you think of a Lie group $G$ for which $\operatorname{Ad}$ has noncompact orbits?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I haven't heard of the Killing form before. So I suppose you are saying that I could use the Killing form to define an $Ad$-invariant norm on $\mathfrak{g}$, provided that the Killing form is definite (not just semi-definite)? And to ensure that the form is definite, I need further assumptions on my compact Lie group $G$?

Comment: @Kajelad Are you suggesting a counter example? As I have already said, I don't have any background knowledge about (compact) Lie groups, so I barely know any examples.

Comment: @user389759 Hint: what is the definition of a compact Lie algebra?

Comment: @Callum I found two definitions: Definition 1 says that it is the Lie algebra of a compact Lie group (in which case the Killing form is negative semidefinite). Definition 2 says that it is a Lie algebra with negative definite Killing form (which implies that it is the Lie algebra of a semi-simple Lie group). So you are saying that the answer to my original question is "no" in general, and "yes" if we assume $G$ to be semi-simple? 
But in the non-semi-simple case, it could in principle still be possible to find a norm that does the job. We just can't use the Killing form for that in that case.

Comment: The 1st definition just includes Lie algebras which are the sum of a negative definite part (i.e. ones in the 2nd def) and an abelian part so hopefully you can see a way to combine your abelian examples with the negative definite example to get a form that works.

Comment: @Callum Ah, now I see. Thanks for your help!